# MySQL Performance - "Redundancy" vs Speed/System Performance

Tags: php, mysql, performance, redundancy

So... assuming i have a database with three tables:
Table **clients**
Table **data**
and Table **clients_to_data**

And I have a API which allows Clients to Access data from Table **data**. Every client has a record in Table **clients** (with things like IP adress etc.) To log who accesses what, i'm logging in the table **clients_to_data** (which contains the ID for table **clients**, table **data** and a timestamp.)
Every time a user access my API, he get's logged in the **clients_to_data** table. (So records in **clients** and **data** are not updated, just read.)
I also want to be able to get the amount of hits per client. Pretty easy, just query the **clients_to_data** table with a client_id and count the results. But as my DB grows, i'll have tenthousands of records in the **clients_to_data** table.
And here's my question: 
Is it a better practice to add a field "hits" to Table **clients** that stores the amount of hits for that user and increment it every time the user queries the API
So this would be adding `redundancy` to the DB which i've heard generally is a bad thing. But in this case i think it would speed up the process of retrieving the amount of hits. 
So which method is better and faster in this case? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Faster when?
Appending to the table will be faster , than finding the record and updating it, much faster than reading it, incrementing and updating it.

However having hits "precalulated", will be faster than the aggregate query to count them.

What you gain on the swings you lose on the roundabouts, which choice you make depends on your current usage patterns. So are you prepared to slow down adding a hit, to gain a signicant boost on finding out how many you've had?

Comment: @tony : Can you comment on my answer?. Is that a good approach?

Answer (score 2):

Obviously selecting a single integer column from a table will be faster then selecting a count() of rows from a table.

The complexity trade off is a bit moot. 1 way you need to write a more complex sql, the other way you will need to update/insert 2 tables in your code.

How often is the number of hits queried? Do you clients look it up, or do you check it once a month?  If you only look now and then I probably wouldn't be too concerned about the time taken to select count(*).

If your clients look up the hit count with every request, then I would look at storing a hits column.

Comment: Yeah, the amount of hits is checked every request (without an API Key you get limited hits per day). I'll use an extra field for the hits then. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Now that our table structures are all clearly defined, lets get to work.

You want to record something in the DB which is the number of times every client has accessed the data, in other terms,

Insert a record into a table "client_to_data" for every clients "impression".

You are worried about 2 things,

**1. Redundancy

2. Performance when retrieving the count**

What about the performance when storing the count.(Insert statements)..?

**This is a classic scenario, where I would write the data to be inserted into memcache, and do a bulk insert at the end of the day.**

**More importantly, I will normalize the data before inserting it to the DB.
As to select, create indexes. If its text, install sphinx.**

Thanks.

Comment: interesting approach, i'll have a look at memcache, never worked with it

Comment: And what happens when the server crashes before the end of the day?  You lose all of those statistics

Comment: @tubaguy50035 : I hadnt considered that!

Comment: Obviously it all depends on how important that data is to you.  If it's just a "nice-to-have" sort of thing, maybe losing a day's worth of data isn't terrible.  If it is, you could still use memcache with some sort of cron job that writes the current count to the database every so often.

Comment: memcache approch is probably a decent approach for this sort of data. You might lose a batch every now and then, but unless you are very unlucky it won't have a an impact on the sort of stats you'd build off this sort of data. i work on high integrity systems so it's not the sort of solution that would occur to me.